# Publishing multiple data types in one ros topic in Arduino

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I followed this tutorial for rosserial in arduino [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World)
But here in this tutorial I need to add different ros topics for every new data types like string, int ,float etc. What if I want to publish multiple data types in a single ros topic ? What should I do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232187/publishing-multiple-data-types-in-one-ros-topic-in-arduino/) by [pankaj patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/26256/pankaj-patel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't publish multiple data types to a single topic. What you need to do is publish multiple topics from a single node.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pankaj patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/26256/pankaj-patel/) on 2016-04-19**:
Thanks Nicholas for replying, I am reading an arduino mega board by ros. I have string, integer and float data coming from arduino and I want to print all data in one terminal. But I can see only one type of data in one terminal by rostopic echo. How can I do this ? I am new to ROS.

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-04-19**:
You could make a custom message that holds a string, integer, and float. Populate that message type in your node and publish it.

**Comment by [pankaj patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/26256/pankaj-patel/) on 2016-04-20**:
Hi Nicholas I made header file for string and integer data type as you said. Now I am having another issue I posted here :[link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/232355/tried-to-publish-before-configured-topic-id-125/)